# Do Vigilantes also get Feats, or only Talents?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, character-advancement

Vigilantes get "social talents" at every other level (1st, 3rd, etc) and Vigilante Talents in between (2nd, 4th, etc) do they still take feats on top of this?

Edit: Thanks for all the replies, two sets of talents and normal feats seemed too good to be true but hey ho.  Also thanks for the bonus warnings against variant multiclassing,  won't be going anywhere near it.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. When you can, it's useful for questions to link to rules elements the questions mention to help folks locate them more easily… and help you more quickly. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Which book does the Vigilante stem from?

Comment: @Trish Vigilante is from Ultimate Intrigue

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Every character** in Pathfinder gets a feat at each odd level. This is completely unrelated to your class and there is really no way to lose them.<sup>1</sup> Some classes, like fighter, get *bonus* feats, that is, extra feats on top of the default one-every-odd-level, but in those cases the feats usually are restricted to some particular list—the fighter can only choose combat feats for his bonus feats, the ranger can only choose the feats on the list for his combat style for his bonus feats, and so on. Regular feats, though, can just be any feat the character qualifies for.

The vigilante doesn’t get bonus feats, so that’s not a concern for you. You just get your normal feat every odd level. If you are human, you get a bonus feat as a racial feature.<sup>2</sup>

1. <sub>Variant multiclassing, kind-of-sort-of, but that’s more like just committing to taking five particular feats—also, no one should ever do it because it is 100% trap 100% of the time.</sub>
2. <sub>And that one can be any feat you qualify for, too; this is part of why human is often the best race choice for just about everything—and when it isn’t *the best*, it’s always second- or third-best, in the worst case.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

## A [vigilante](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/vigilante) also gets feats

It may seem like a lot of choices, but like any other class, a creature that takes levels in the base class [vigilante](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/vigilante) typically gains one or more feats at level 1 and additional feats when the creature [advances in levels](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/). The class would have to say specifically that it removes the creature's normal feat progression for the creature *not* to gain its normal allotment of feats.

Answer (score 5):

#### Yes.

All characters get feats at [every odd level](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/#Advancing_Your_Character). Some classes give *bonus* feats at certain levels, but **every** character gets a feat at 1st, 3rd, 5th, etc. The only exception to this is characters who use [variant multiclassing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/#Variant_Multiclassing), which is a terrible system that should be avoided at all costs.